# How to make clojure tools.analyzer ignore validation step?

Tags: clojure, abstract-syntax-tree

The initial task I want to solve is to build AST for an arbitrary Clojure code. So google suggests to use https://github.com/clojure/tools.analyzer.jvm for this purpose. I've tried this library on the simple Clojure form `(print x)` and this raised exception with message **Could not resolve var: x**. I used to think of building AST as a simple process without side-effects like validation, resolving variables and so on. It's also weird that there is no clean documentation on how one could omit this variable resolution step.

Comment: I played with an option :validate/unresolvable-symbol-handler - `(aj/analyze
               '(print x)
               (assoc (aj/empty-env)
                      :passes-opts {:validate/unresolvable-symbol-handler
                                    (fn [a b c] (print a)) }))` but had no luck

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. The `:validate/unresolvable-symbol-handler` has to be passed with `:passes-opts` as a 3rd argument (not inside the `environment` as I tried)

```clj
(clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm/analyze '(print x) 
    (clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm/empty-env)
    {:passes-opts {:validate/unresolvable-symbol-handler
                                     (fn [a b c] nil)}})
```